# Expo standalone android app doesn't display splash image

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

json is as follows. The splash image in the ios standalone app works perfectly whereas it doesn't work on the android standalone for some reason. On the android platform a blank screen with the color #172A3F is displayed but not the splash image. It works when I use the url expo app provides on both platforms.

```
"android": {
  "package": "work.myapp.mobile",
  "versionCode": 36,
  "icon": "./icon.png",
  "permissions": [
    "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
  ],
  "splash": {
    "backgroundColor": "#172A3F",
    "ldpi": "./app/assets/images/splash-v2.png",
    "mdpi": "./app/assets/images/splash-v2.png",
    "hdpi": "./app/assets/images/splash-v2.png",
    "xhdpi": "./app/assets/images/splash-v2.png",
    "xxhdpi": "./app/assets/images/splash-v2.png",
    "xxxhdpi": "./app/assets/images/splash-v2.png",
    "resizeMode": "cover"
  },
  "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
      "apiKey": "myappkey"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is ./app/assets the correct path? Not ./assets?

Comment: No that's the correct path